# Stop schedule command execution in Laravel

Tags: laravel, cron, command, schedule

Can I stop an specific command runnig in the Laravel (7) schedule? I need to stop a command excecution, I was looking for any solution but I didn't find it...

Comment: You can use `->when(Closure)`  with a schedule to run the command when a certain condition is fulfilled else the command will be stoped.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadYasir but...if the schedule is running and I need to stop it (or a specific command) how I do it?

Comment: It is pretty silly of me to ask that do you have access to the code on the server? if yes then you can comment or remove that specific command from `kernel.php`. This file is located in your laravel project's directory `app\console`.

Comment: Hi! Yes I have access to the code and i can comment it. But...if the command is currently running...how i can stop it?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me after I found a fault in my scheduled code and it was going to keep running for a really long time. `SSH` into the server.

```
ps -fe | grep artisan
```

then kill PID (PID being the number of the process). Killing the first two results worked for me.

Note: If you are using `withoutOverlapping()` the process will not start up again unless you change the `->name()` to something `unique`.

Comment: Yes, manually executed commands, appears on when I execute: ps -fe | grep artisan...but, the commands running from schedule don't appear...